# Erro ao incluir a class no arquivo index assim não consigo instanciar ela [PHP]

Tags: php

Olá tenho dois arquivo o **INDEX.PHP** que se localiza na raiz do projeto e o Arquivo **SYSTEM.PHP** que se localiza dentro da pasta **LIB**.

Resumo do Arquivo **INDEX**

```
<?php 
  define('APP_ROOT', 'home');
  require_once 'config/Bootstrap.php';
  require_once 'lib/System.php';
  $System = new System();
  $System->start();
```

Resumo do arquivo **SYSTEM**

```
<?php 
  namespace lib;
  require_once 'Router.php';
  class System extends Router {

   Aqui contem o method **START**

  }
```

O php retorna o seguinte erro: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'System' not found in 'Meu diretorio'**

Já dei um var_dump exists_file no caminho direto da INDEX para o caminho lib/System.php e retornou **TRUE**, o caminho está correto mas pq não encontro a class?

Answer (score 1):

A sua classe `System` pertence ao namespace `lib` e, portanto, seu "nome completo" (ou *fully-qualified name*) é `lib\System`.  Sendo assim, para invocá-la, você precisa referencia-la por seu "nome completo".

```php
// ...
$System = new lib\System();
```

Ou usar *aliases*:

```php
require_once 'caminho/para/arquivo.php';

use lib\System; 

$System = new System();
```

Ou ainda,

```php
require_once 'caminho/para/arquivo.php';

use lib\System as MyClass;

$System = new MyClass();
```

Comment: @Otávio Se você acha que minha resposta solucionou seu problema, clica no "vezinho" que está na esqueda da minha resposta (veja aqui [como aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)) para ajudar a comunidade. Obrigado